# Creating directory in c

Tags: c, mkdir

I am working on some c code and am trying to programmatically create a directory. I found a while ago the mkdir(file, "w+) function to make the directory writable once its created but I've just noticed its creating a warning when compiled

```
warning: passing argument 2 of âmkdirâ makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Below is the code I am using

```
void checkLogDirectoryExistsAndCreate()
{
    struct stat st;
    char logPath[FILE_PATH_BUF_LEN];
    sprintf(logPath, "%s/logs", logRotateConfiguration->logFileDir);
    if (stat(logPath, &st) != 0)
    {
        printf("Making log directory\n");
        mkdir(logPath, "w+");
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this manpage](http://home.fhtw-berlin.de/~junghans/cref/MAN/mkdir.htm), the 2nd parameter is a `mode_t`, which is a numeric type and gives the wanted access mode of the directory. Here you should provide `0777`, an octal number meaning all of `r`, `w` and `x`, and this is restricted by the `umask`.

I don't know which of these informations apply to Windows.

Answer (score 5):

The second argument of [mkdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir) should be of type `mode_t`.  The [chmod](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/chmod.2.html) man page lists available modes (which can be OR'd together).

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter of the `mkdir` function is not a string. It's a flag combination to define the mode.

See [the mkdir manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir) for more information. See [sys/stat.h](http://linux.die.net/include/sys/stat.h) for the complete flag list (search for "S_IRWXU")